# How to display model data in QML not using delegate

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have a simple QML form, which contains just input boxes. The form also have two buttons “Backward” and “Forward”.

The form filled from data, contained in one row of QT model. Buttons are used to change a row, currently displayed in the form.

How can I accomplish this use case? Say, for Qt 5.9

**UPD:** I have found an “Object Instance” type of the model. Maybe it’s it? I explain my concern: is my task common and have recommended solution, or it is not - it’s something special and non-standard.

Comment: Can you maybe add some mockup images (paint or so) of how you want it working?

Comment: @Amfasis to simplify the case just imagine a form with single input box and two buttons, data for the form is a simple list of strings. I want to display and edit one single string from the list in the form and be able to change current string using two buttons.

Comment: Ok, I don't think it's that common, but still, can do a shot on a solution. What it your "QT model", QAbstractListModel?

Comment: @Amfasis actually, I don’t know, what kind of base model type to use in this situation. What approach do you suppose?

Comment: You can go with a `ListModel` entirely composed in QML, or QAbstractListModel entirely written in C++. These are the two easiest I would say. Depends on what the rest of the use-case is, should it be QML-only, or is C++ handling going to be needed anyway

Comment: @Amfasis ok. And what to do next? The form is not repeater-like control. It have no delegate property. How I supposed to connect form controls with model? Do all wiring by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to have is something like [`QDataWidgetMapper`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html) but in QML.

If you use a `QAbstractItemModel` (QML `ListModel` is one), you could recreate your own in C++ by listening to the `dataChanged`, `rowsInserted`/`rowsRemoved` signals and friends.

Luckily for you I've also needed that and already wrote it, shameless plug : https://github.com/oKcerG/QmlModelHelper

In your case you could use it like so:

```
property int currentIndex: 0
readonly property QtObject mappedData: myModel.ModelHelper.map(currentIndex) 
TextField {
    text: parent.mappedData.someTextRole
    onAccepted: parent.mappedData.someTextRole = text
}
Button {
    text: "previous"
    enabled: parent.currentIndex > 0
    onClicked: --parent.currentIndex
}
Button {
    text: "next"
    enabled: parent.currentIndex < myModel.ModelHelper.count - 1
    onClicked: ++parent.currentIndex
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you! Will give it a try and write back.